DirectMusic GUID Lnk2001 unresolved external symbol Error
ErrorList
Error LNK2001   unresolved external symbol IID_IDirectMusicPerformance8
Error LNK2001   unresolved external symbol IID_IDirectMusicLoader8
Error LNK2001   unresolved external symbol GUID_ConnectToDLSCollection
Error LNK2001   unresolved external symbol CLSID_DirectMusicPerformance
Error LNK2001   unresolved external symbol CLSID_DirectMusicLoader
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YVcNI4AQh8KjYBRjAH--y_lhi0dftL2_/view?usp=sharing

code, include file, VS file

code
#pragma warning(disable:4244)
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <assert.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
using namespace std;

// Library File Address
#pragma region Library

// DirectX11 3D
#include ".Lib/DX_2007/Include/dxerr9.h"
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <dwrite.h>


#include <dinput.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d12.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")


#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

//#include <Dxerr.h>
//#pragma comment(lib, "dxerr.lib")

#include <dmusicc.h>
#include <dmksctrl.h>
#include ".Lib/DX_2007/Include/dmdls.h"
#include ".Lib/DX_2007/Include/dmusici.h"
#include ".Lib/DX_2007/Include/dmusicf.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "dsound.lib")

#include <InitGuid.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comdlg32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

#include <shellapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")

#include <ole2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

#include <oleauto.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "oleaut32.lib")

#include <uuids.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "uuid.lib")
#include <string>
int main(void)
{
    HINSTANCE inst = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);

    wstring dmimePath = L"../.Lib/dmime.dll";
    inst = LoadLibrary(dmimePath.c_str());
    wstring dmusicPath = L"../.Lib/dmusic.dll";
    inst = LoadLibrary(dmusicPath.c_str());


    IDirectMusicLoader8* loader;
    IDirectMusicPerformance8* performance;
    IDirectMusicSegment8* segment;
    IDirectMusicCollection8* col;
    IDirectMusicAudioPath8* path;


    IDirectMusic8* music;
    IDirectSound* sound;
    DMUS_AUDIOPARAMS param;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CoCreateInstance
    (
        CLSID_DirectMusicLoader,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC,
        IID_IDirectMusicLoader8,
        (void**)&loader
    );

    hr = CoCreateInstance
    (
        CLSID_DirectMusicPerformance,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC,
        IID_IDirectMusicPerformance8,
        (void**)&performance
    );

    hr = performance->InitAudio(
        NULL,                               // IDirectMusic interface not needed.
        NULL,                               // IDirectSound interface not needed.
        NULL,                               // Window handle.
        DMUS_APATH_SHARED_STEREOPLUSREVERB, // Default audiopath type.
        64,                                 // Number of performance channels.
        DMUS_AUDIOF_ALL,                    // Features on synthesizer.
        NULL                                // Audio parameters; use defaults.
    );

    return 0;
}

Playing MIDI music using the DirectMusic.
However, during the initialization of the DirectMusic function, an error occurred that failed to get the GUID.
I've changed the project to x86 to solve this problem, and I've tried to find the library I need as much as I can.
However, there are still problems.
Help me, please.

All #pragma comment(lib must be in stdafx.cpp. It's not visible if stdafx.h is included somewhere. Provide a [mre].

Thank you for advice.
I modified my writing and I found and added a Library List to use DirectMusic, but the problem remains the same.
